# How to select a tree view node in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the the following code sample

```
 private TreeNode AddNode(TreeNode node, string key)
    {
        var child = node.ChildNodes.Cast<TreeNode>().FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Value == key);
        if (child != null)
            return child;
        child = new TreeNode(key, key);
        child.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.SelectExpand;
        child.Selected = true;
        node.ChildNodes.Add(child); 
        return child;
    }
```

I'm not able to select the node. When I invoke **treeview_SelectedNodeChanged**, I'm getting NULL..

```
string v = ((TreeView)sender).SelectedNode.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `treeview.SelectedNode` and check the code in page_load handler,

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
  //code to add nodes
}
```